# Adding different options for Expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list View that has a check button, but the problem is I can only add one child item.

```
    dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
            arCategory.add(dataItem);
            dataItem = new DataItem();
            dataItem.setCategoryName("Art");
            arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
                SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = newSubCategoryItem();        
subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
                subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName("Art: "+j);
                arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
            }
```

I have tried to use but this has no check

```
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                
    // Adding child data            
    listDataHeader.add("do this and do that");
    listDataHeader.add("do this and don't do that");
    listDataHeader.add("don't do that but you can do this");
 
    // Adding child data
    List<String> 250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    250.add("hmm what is this you doing");
  
    // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), 250);    
}
```

but the thing is that one is `HashMap<String, List<String>>()` and the other is `ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>` so it can work.

Is there a way I can make the first code add more item?

This is the adapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.apps.ayodkay.services.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter extends
BaseExpandableListAdapter {

public static ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> childItems;
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parentItems;
//    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> childItems;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Activity activity;
private HashMap<String, String> child;
private int count = 0;
private boolean isFromMyCategoriesFragment;

public MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parentItems,
                                         ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> childItems,boolean isFromMyCategoriesFragment) {

    MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter.parentItems = parentItems;
    MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter.childItems = childItems;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.isFromMyCategoriesFragment = isFromMyCategoriesFragment;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return parentItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return (childItems.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
     final ViewHolderParent viewHolderParent;
    if (convertView == null) {

        if(isFromMyCategoriesFragment) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_layout_my_categories, null);
        }else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_layout_choose_categories, null);
        }
        viewHolderParent = new ViewHolderParent();

        viewHolderParent.tvMainCategoryName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMainCategoryName);
        viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbMainCategory);
        viewHolderParent.ivCategory = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCategory);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolderParent);
    } else {
        viewHolderParent = (ViewHolderParent) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (parentItems.get(groupPosition).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED).equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE)) {
        viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.setChecked(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    } else {
        viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.setChecked(false);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.isChecked()) {
                parentItems.get(groupPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);

                for (int i = 0; i < childItems.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
                    childItems.get(groupPosition).get(i).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            else {
                parentItems.get(groupPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
                for (int i = 0; i < childItems.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
                    childItems.get(groupPosition).get(i).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    ConstantManager.childItems = childItems;
    ConstantManager.parentItems = parentItems;

    viewHolderParent.tvMainCategoryName.setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_NAME));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, final boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    final ViewHolderChild viewHolderChild;
    child = childItems.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_list_layout_choose_category, null);
        viewHolderChild = new ViewHolderChild();

        viewHolderChild.tvSubCategoryName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubCategoryName);
        viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbSubCategory);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolderChild);
    } else {
        viewHolderChild = (ViewHolderChild) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (childItems.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED).equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE)) {
        viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.setChecked(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.setChecked(false);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    viewHolderChild.tvSubCategoryName.setText(child.get(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_CATEGORY_NAME));
    viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.isChecked()) {
                count = 0;
                childItems.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                count = 0;
                childItems.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < childItems.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
                if (childItems.get(groupPosition).get(i).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED).equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == childItems.get(groupPosition).size()) {
                parentItems.get(groupPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                parentItems.get(groupPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            ConstantManager.childItems = childItems;
            ConstantManager.parentItems = parentItems;
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

private class ViewHolderParent {

    TextView tvMainCategoryName;
    CheckBox cbMainCategory;
    ImageView ivCategory;
}

private class ViewHolderChild {

    TextView tvSubCategoryName;
    CheckBox cbSubCategory;
}


}
```

Comment: Please post ExpandableListView adapter for the first code.

Comment: @I_A_Mok i have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have custom classes similar to these:

DataItem:

```
public class DataItem {
private String categoryName;
private ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> subCategory;
private boolean isChecked;

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

public ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> getSubCategory() {
    return subCategory;
}

public void setSubCategory(ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> subCategory) {
    this.subCategory = subCategory;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    isChecked = checked;
}

public DataItem(){
    categoryName = "Default Category";
    subCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    isChecked = false;
}
}
```

SubCategoryItem:

```
public class SubCategoryItem {
private String subCategoryName;
private boolean isChecked;

public String getSubCategoryName() {
    return subCategoryName;
}

public void setSubCategoryName(String subCategoryName) {
    this.subCategoryName = subCategoryName;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    isChecked = checked;
}

public SubCategoryItem(){
    subCategoryName = "Default Sub Category";
    isChecked = false;
}
}
```

Then you can use those directly for the adapter, like below:

```
public class MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
public ArrayList<DataItem> dataList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Activity activity;
private int count;
private boolean isFromMyCategoriesFragment;

public MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<DataItem> dataList, boolean isFromMyCategoriesFragment) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.isFromMyCategoriesFragment = isFromMyCategoriesFragment;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return dataList.get(groupPosition).getSubCategory().size();
}

@Override
public DataItem getGroup(int i) {
    return dataList.get(i);
}

@Override
public SubCategoryItem getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return dataList.get(i).getSubCategory().get(i1);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ViewHolderParent viewHolderParent;
    if (convertView == null) {
        if(isFromMyCategoriesFragment) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_layout_my_categories, null);
        }else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_layout_choose_categories, null);
        }
        viewHolderParent = new ViewHolderParent();

        viewHolderParent.tvMainCategoryName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMainCategoryName);
        viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbMainCategory);
        viewHolderParent.ivCategory = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCategory);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolderParent);
    } else {
        viewHolderParent = (ViewHolderParent) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.setChecked(dataList.get(groupPosition).isChecked());

    viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dataList.get(groupPosition).setChecked(viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.isChecked());
            for (int i = 0; i < dataList.get(groupPosition).getSubCategory().size(); i++) {
                dataList.get(groupPosition).getSubCategory().get(i).setChecked(viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.isChecked());
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    //ConstantManager.childItems = childItems;
    //ConstantManager.parentItems = parentItems;

    viewHolderParent.tvMainCategoryName.setText(dataList.get(groupPosition).getCategoryName());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, final boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ViewHolderChild viewHolderChild;
    SubCategoryItem child = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_list_layout_choose_category, null);
        viewHolderChild = new ViewHolderChild();

        viewHolderChild.tvSubCategoryName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubCategoryName);
        viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbSubCategory);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolderChild);
    } else {
        viewHolderChild = (ViewHolderChild) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.setChecked(child.isChecked());

    viewHolderChild.tvSubCategoryName.setText(child.getSubCategoryName());
    viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).setChecked(viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.isChecked());
            count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < getGroup(groupPosition).getSubCategory().size(); i++) {
                if (getChild(groupPosition, i).isChecked()) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            getGroup(groupPosition).setChecked(count == getGroup(groupPosition).getSubCategory().size());
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            //ConstantManager.childItems = childItems;
            //ConstantManager.parentItems = parentItems;
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

private class ViewHolderParent {
    TextView tvMainCategoryName;
    CheckBox cbMainCategory;
    ImageView ivCategory;
}

private class ViewHolderChild {
    TextView tvSubCategoryName;
    CheckBox cbSubCategory;
}

public ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> getCheckedList() {
    ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> checkedItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataItem dataItem : dataList) {
        for (SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem : dataItem.getSubCategory()) {
            if(subCategoryItem.isChecked()) checkedItemList.add(subCategoryItem);
        }
    }
    return  checkedItemList;
}

}
```

Create the data list like this:

```
    String[] sampleGroups = {"Art", "Maths", "Language"};
    ArrayList<DataItem> arCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < sampleGroups.length; i++){
        DataItem dataItem = new DataItem();
        dataItem.setCategoryName(sampleGroups[i]);
        ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
            SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
            subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName(dataItem.getCategoryName() + ": " + j);
            arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
        }
        dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
        arCategory.add(dataItem);
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the help, but here     `subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName(dataItem.getCategoryName() + ": " + j);`   i would like to add more subcategory items and and also know who which subcategory was checked thanks

Comment: For my sample code, you can have 3 groups and ecah have 5 children. Both groups and children are in ArrayList that can add data. Therefore I don't understand what is the problem **add more subcategory items**. Pls make a screenshot of what you get now and edit it to show what you expect.

Comment: Around the end of the adapter, I added a public method **getCheckedList()** which creates an array list of checked children. Hope that helps!